# XPND file extensions. What are they?

Tags: html, perl, include, file-extension

There's been a problem which has been troubling me recently. I've discovered some files using the extension **.xpnd** while looking through some Perl examples. Their contents were mostly plain HTML, with the following exception:

**[% INCLUDE path_to_random_file.xpnd %]**

Could somebody enlighten me on the nature of these files and of that tag?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like some templating. where did you see them?

Comment: An archive with some work of a friend of mine. The files with that extension were in a folder called templates if I remember it right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the .xpnd file extension.  However, the [% INCLUDE .. %] directive is part of the Template Toolkit (see http://www.template-toolkit.org/) and is used to include templates within templates.  I suspect that the .xpnd files are templates local to that particular system and may represent HTML (or whatever) that has been "expanded" by some other part of the system for inclusion in higher level templates.  Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I reckon that this should be the answer.